# How can i center a div in a parallax background image

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I'd like to horizontally and vertically center a div with a parallax background image. I've tried `bootstrap 4` class `d-block`, `mx-auto`, `text-center`. It centered it horizontally but not vertically. How can I also center it vertically?

```css
.parallax_bg {
  background: url(assets/img/corinne-kutz-211251.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
}

.parallax {
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.parallax_text > p {
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<section data-stellar-background-ratio="0.5" class="parallax parallax_bg text-center mx-auto d-block">
  <div class="parallax_text">
    <h3><em>Venenatis Nisl Porta</em></h3>
    <p>Lorem vestibulum gravida ipsum non velit aliquam</p>
    <a class="btn btn-primary mt-3" href="#">Read More&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-angle-double-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just apply `position: relative` to `parallax` class and then apply the following css to the `parallax_text` class:

```
.parallax_text {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try flex like this :

```css
.parallax_bg {
  background: url(https://lorempixel.com/400/400/);
  background-size: cover;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
}

.parallax {
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height: 120vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.parallax_text {
  background: #fff;
}

.parallax_text>p {
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<section data-stellar-background-ratio="0.5" class="parallax parallax_bg text-center mx-auto d-block">
  <div class="parallax_text">
    <h3><em>Venenatis Nisl Porta</em></h3>
    <p>Lorem vestibulum gravida ipsum non velit aliquam</p>
    <a class="btn btn-primary mt-3" href="#">Read More&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-angle-double-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
  </div>
</section>
```