# Centering text inside of parallax image made with SimpleParallax.js

Tags: css, parallax, text-alignment

I'm **very new** to coding and I'm trying to add some subheader text to a parallax image on my project. I created the parallax effect with [SimpleParallax.js](https://simpleparallax.com/) and put it, and an h2 subhead, inside of a div, but the text just sits underneath the photo. I implemented the solution outlined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47864663/how-can-i-center-a-div-in-a-parallax-background-image)

I added position: relative styling to the parallax class and the following code to the h2 text:

`position: absolute;   top: 50%;   left: 50%;   transform: translate(-50%, -50%)`

But, the text still isn't positioned correctly. It moves the text all the way to the top of the page where the h1 text is.

I need help figuring out how to situate the h2 text inside of the parallax image, ideally center-left justified.

This is a snippet of the problem area:

```
<header>
        <img src="https://cdn.glitch.me/7cebc84e-df9c-45e9-95c1- 
516a7a17465b/Header.jpg?v=1675454184505" class="header-image" alt="A 
rendered image of our funky trike" />
        <h1 class="header-text">Join us for a Funk-Filled Ride as we 
<br> Roll Out, Pop Up, and Get Down!</h1>
</header>

<div>       
    <img class="frame-2" src="https://cdn.glitch.global/7cebc84e- 
df9c-45e9-95c1-516a7a17465b/Frame-2.jpg?v=1675454173228">
    <h2 class="subhead-text">Roll Out: our portable party can go 
wherever you go</h2>
</div>

<style>
.header-image {
 width: 100%;
}
.header-text {
  color: #f3f3f3;
  font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 7vh;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-style: italic; 
  background-color: #f41230bd; 
  width: 85%;
  padding: 5px;
}
.subhead-text {
  color: #f3f3f3;
  font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-style: italic; 
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%)
}
.frame-2 {
  position: relative;
} </style>
```

The whole project is available on [Code Pen](https://codepen.io/elijah-messmer/pen/abjXwxd).

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Please add [mre] here not in codepen

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.